# Iterate over certain matrix cells

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-matrix

I have a matrix and want to reference several nodes of this matrix.
How do I add a line for some of the cells?

I came up with this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes]
        {1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\};

        \foreach \i in {0, 3}
        {
                \pgfmathsetmacro\iplusone{1+\i}
                \pgfmathsetmacro\itimesfour{4*\i}
                \draw (m-1-\iplusone .south) -- node [at end] {\itimesfour} +(0, -1);
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which is a simplified version of what I want to do.
However, this does not work and gives the error:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `s' or `so' (in '0.south').
```

I don't know where to start with this error at hand.

Comment: You need to use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` otherwise you have a another `.` in the output: `(m-1-0.0.south)` (TikZ parses that as node name `m-1-0` and anchor `0.south` which it tries as an angle since no anchor is named `0.south`. Besides that, there is a spurious `{` right before the relative coordinate and `\itemtimesfour` should be `\itimesfour`.